# Can't get git filter-repo to work - No files are removed

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner, git-filter-repo

We have a git repo that had some code we didn't want visible publicly pushed to a public repo.  I am trying to use git filter-repo to remove the files from the repo.

I have created a text file containing the relative paths to the files I want removed in, called to_remove.txt.

to_remove.txt:

```
...
src\unwanted_code\a.c
src\unwanted_code\b.c
src\unwanted_code\c.c
src\unwanted_code\d.c
...
```

I though this operation would be as simple as CD'ing into a fresh clone of the repo and running the following command:

```
git filter-repo --paths-from-file to_remove.txt --invert-paths
```

Upon running this command with the --debug flag, I can see that the file is being read and the paths are being put into the filter.  The command will run without fault, but when I check my local clone of the repo, literally nothing has changed and all of the unwanted .c files are still there.  I am confused what I am doing wrong.  Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Are you checking the clone _that you ran filter-repo in_ or a completely different clone?

Comment: @user1686 the same clone that I ran filter-repo

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve]. Can you add the complete set of steps you're executing? From cloning the repository, to cd'ing into the repository, to running `git filter-repo`. Include the output produced by `git filter-repo`.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved this issue.  The problem was that my to_removed.txt has \ instead of /.  Should have looked like this:

```
...
src/unwanted_code/a.c
src/unwanted_code/b.c
src/unwanted_code/c.c
src/unwanted_code/d.c
...
```